# How do I reload the formatted text into RTB?

Tags: vb.net

I have a RTB in VB.NET, and put an event handler to save the formatted text into a file after encrypting it. However, I can't figure out how to reload the formatting - when I open it, it shows the symbols of formatting instead of formatted text. Here's my code:

```
Dim FileName As String = TextBox1.Text
File.Delete(FileName)
Dim EncryptElement As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
            EncryptElement.Key = {AscW("B"c), AscW("A"c), AscW("1"c), AscW("R"c), AscW("3"c), AscW("9"c), AscW("G"c), AscW("V"c), AscW("5"c), AscW("S"c), AscW("P"c), AscW("0"c), AscW("L"c), AscW("Z"c), AscW("4"c), AscW("M"c)} '128 bit Key
            EncryptElement.IV = {AscW("N"c), AscW("B"c), AscW("5"c), AscW("3"c), AscW("G"c), AscW("L"c), AscW("2"c), AscW("Q"c)} ' 64 bit Initialization Vector

Dim fStream As FileStream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
Dim cStream As New CryptoStream(fStream, New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(EncryptElement.Key, EncryptElement.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)

Dim sWriter As New StreamWriter(cStream)

sWriter.WriteLine(RichTextBox1.Rtf)

sWriter.Close()
cStream.Close()
fStream.Close()
```

The above code is for saving, and the below code is for opening.

```
Dim FileName As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim DecryptElement As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
            DecryptElement.Key = {AscW("B"c), AscW("A"c), AscW("1"c), AscW("R"c), AscW("3"c), AscW("9"c), AscW("G"c), AscW("V"c), AscW("5"c), AscW("S"c), AscW("P"c), AscW("0"c), AscW("L"c), AscW("Z"c), AscW("4"c), AscW("M"c)}
            DecryptElement.IV = {AscW("N"c), AscW("B"c), AscW("5"c), AscW("3"c), AscW("G"c), AscW("L"c), AscW("2"c), AscW("Q"c)}

 Dim fStream As FileStream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

 Dim cStream As New CryptoStream(fStream, New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateDecryptor(DecryptElement.Key, DecryptElement.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read)

 Dim sReader As New StreamReader(cStream)

 Dim DecryptedData As String = ""

 DecryptedData = sReader.ReadToEnd

 RichTextBox1.AppendText(DecryptedData)
 RichTextBox1.Enabled = True
 Button1.Text = "OK"

 sReader.Close()
 cStream.Close()
 fStream.Close()
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need RichTextBox1.SaveFile(SomeStream, RichTextBoxStreamType) I think StreamWriter is stuffing it up.

Oh and seeing as you just gave the world the keys for your encryption you might want to come up with a new one...

Added after comment not proven though.

Replace these two lines in your save routine

```
Dim sWriter As New StreamWriter(cStream)
sWriter.WriteLine(RichTextBox1.Rtf)
```

with

```
RichTextBox1.SaveFile(cStream,RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

and get rid of `swriter.Close()`

I think.

Comment: Something like this in your save routine

Comment: Same issue other end? RichTextBox has a LoadFile method. Ditch the StreamReader (which is plain text) and pass the decrypted stream to RichTextBox1.LoadFile.

Comment: Dim fStream As FileStream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

  Dim cStream As CryptoStream...  

  RichTextBox1.LoadFile(cStream, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)  

This gives a System.NotSupportedException saying that the stream does not support seeking.. I removed the DecryptedData string and sReader

Comment: I dunno, save the decrypted stuff to a new memory stream, set position back to 0 and then pass that to loadfile maybe.